# Which colour space should I apply Image sharpening filter?

Tags: image-processing, video-processing

I am trying to apply a Image sharpening 2D filter kernel(Laplacian) on a Image in my proprietary Image/Video processing pipeline(From Camera raw to final JPEG/MPEG). I plan to perform 2D convolution of this Laplacian kernel with the 2D image array to sharpen the image. My questions is :-

What is the most suitable colour space to apply this image sharpening filter to get best output image quality

a) Should I apply this filter on each component(R,G, & B) in the RGB space?

or

b)Should I apply this in the YUV space and only on Y component (or should it be also applied on U and V components)?

Any pointers will be useful.

**EDIT:** I asked this here, since I plan to do it programatically, myself. No external tool.

thank you.

-AD.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably do it to only the Y in YUV.

In RGB you would have to be careful not to introduce color fringing.

Comment: That's right, and the effect is demonstrated in this answer to the same question: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8479/which-colour-space-should-i-apply-image-sharpening-filter/8484#8484